# Submitting oozie jobs using keytab

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos, oozie, keytab

I am using a keytab file to bypass kerberos to run a shell script through oozie. Shell script includes hbase shell commands so I nee to do a kinit before running hbase shell commands.This works fine for me.

So, in a case where I launch the job using a coordinator and have several shell scripts in the workflow using a keytab(service account) will there be a conflict in oozie ?Since I launch the job using oozie coordinator but have keytab files in workflow of a service account.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keytab files need to exist on all hadoop data nodes. Your shell scripts need them when running as a oozie job/map task to execute kinit for service accounts.

When deploying keytab files to data nodes of shared cluster, it's best to set file permission correctly so that other hadoop jobs will not have access to it.

Comment: I am adding keytab to distributed cache via the <file> option solve this. Please let me know if this is right approach.

Comment: I think it's fine choice to use distributed cache to push keytab files to job. Having keytab file provisioned in data node makes it available to all jobs running on that cluster. With distributed cache, it's job specific. Every job will need to add this file property. Both work with different scenarios. :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do it using distributed cache? I had it in HDFS and have tried to copy it to local from HDFS and use it to generate tickets. But it is throwing CONN_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_GET_TICKETCACHE exception.

Comment: You need to add it to the using the file tag and also the file should reside in the oozie workflow deployment directory on HDFS. File tag looks something like this for every action<file>keytabfilename#keytabfilename</file>